# Recognizing the right expression to complete in insert mode

Tags: plugin-vimtex, ins-completion

When one triggers a  completion, vim guesses what was the expression (behind the cursor) that you want to complete. I don't fully understand the logic, but it seems that it assumes that the expression is a sequence of alphabetic chars+some additional.

Suppose I have a graph named "G_{walk}" (I do have - latex). I want to refer to it.

I can trigger a completion that would recognize it when I type `G_<c-x><c-n>`. But if I type `G_{<c-x><c-n>`, it regards whatever that follows `{` as a completely different expression and it won't find "G_{walk}".

So, how can I control the expression? 
Sometimes I just want it to ignore all its stupid rules, and complete from the moment I press a key and until I tell it to stop. Can it be done?

Thanks.

PS I did read about ins-completion. I don't understand how what I see in `syntax list` or how `omnifunction` related to the question  I asked about `<c-x><c-n>` as main example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of auto-completion works with **keywords**, so the set of characters that make up possible completion prefixes and candidates is controlled by the [`'iskeyword'` setting](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27).

For instance, under [`:help compl-current`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#compl-current) you'll find:

> If there is a keyword in front of the cursor (a name made out of alphabetic characters and characters in `'iskeyword'`), it is used as the search pattern, with `"\<"` prepended (meaning: start of a word). [...]

Most other types of completion will typically follow the same definition of keywords.

In your particular case, in order to be able to complete `G_{walk}`, you might want to consider including the curly brace characters in the set of valid keyword characters, which you can do with:

```
:set iskeyword+={,}
```

Note that this might affect keyword splitting elsewhere, since `{` and `}` are used in TeX/LaTeX for parameters, some words that were previously considered keywords on their own will cease to do so. You should consider this trade-off if you decide to touch the `'iskeyword'` setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't understand that since they wrote: "in front of the cursor" and it seems behind. I think that any keyword/command that is essential to the language appears in omnifunction offered by vimtex and so it won't matter. All seems well anyway.

Comment: After I have done the change, folding didn't work. But then I installed vim-tex-fold and it got right.